# I want to get the sum of digits of minimum element in the array and check if the sum is even or odd in c

Tags: c

I have written this code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int getSum(int);
int getDigitSum(int *arr, int len)
{
    int result;
    int min;
    for (int i = 0, min = arr[0]; i<len; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]<min) {
            min = arr[i];
            printf("min=%d\n", min);
        }
    }
    printf("minimum=%d\n", min);
    result = getSum(min);
    if (result % 2 == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int getSum(int num)
{
    int rem, sum = 0;
    while (num)
    {
        rem = num % 10;
        sum += rem;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
void main() {
    int arr[5] = { 211,612,111,129,156 };
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    int i = getDigitSum(arr, 5);
    if (i == 1)
        printf("Even");
    else
        printf("Odd");
}
```

But the **min** value in the getDigitSum()  is getting changed outside for loop even after declaring it before the loop starts.
Here is the output-

```
211 612 111 129 156
min=111
minimum=-2
Even
```

Please tell me why the value is changing like this?

Comment: Please ___properly___ indent your code. Machine (Compiler) can read and compile anything, but for humans, it needs to make a little _sense_ while reading a block of text as _code_. Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `for(int i = 0, min = arr[0]; ...)` this statement is interpreted as a declaration and initialization of a min value inside the for-block when the for ends, the new min variable is removed too.

Try to initialize the variable with the declaration

```
//...
int min = arr[0];
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
//...
```

Comment: Why the new 'min' value is also getting removed?

Comment: Because this is inside a new block of code when the block ends all the variables inside the scope of the block are removed.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: Is there any way to use 'min=arr[0]' as the initializing statement inside for loop? The question requires to be done in this approach.